# Does all applications which show graphics without an X server has to use the frame buffer device on linux?

Tags: linux, console, framebuffer

I am using limelight embedded on my raspberry pi 2. The application streams games from your Windows PC.

It is not an X application because no X server is running.

1. So does this application has to access the frame buffer device or are there other methods of screen rendering besides using the fbdevice or an X server on linux?
2. I noticed that the application (limelight embedded) shows on all tty's. Is this normal behavior when using the frame buffer device or could it be possible to use for example an X server on another tty but limelight embedded just does not support this?